# How to properly link to a modularized dependency using the Maven Javadoc Plugin?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, java-platform-module-system, maven-javadoc-plugin

In my `project`, I'm trying to include links to a modularized Java library ([Caesar](https://github.com/Glusk/caesar)) in the documentation files generated by the `javadoc` tool. Running:

```
mvn clean install
```

builds the docs without links to the external library.

My configuration:

```
project
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    `-- main
        `-- java
            |-- foo.bar.project
            |   `-- foo
            |       `-- bar
            |           `-- project
            |               `-- Foo.java
            `-- module-info.java
```

**`Foo.java`**:

```
package foo.bar.project;

import com.github.glusk.caesar.Bytes;

public class Foo {
    public static Bytes bytes;
}
```

**`module-info.java`**:

```
module foo.bar.project {
    requires com.github.glusk.caesar;
}
```

**`pom.xml`**:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.glusk</groupId>
      <artifactId>caesar</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
                <id>compile</id>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <sourcepath>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourcepath>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>attach-javadocs</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

---

System info:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T20:41:47+02:00)
Maven home: C:\Tools\apache-maven-3.6.0
Java version: 11.0.8, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.8
Default locale: sl_SI, platform encoding: UTF8
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

After adding the Maven Dependency Plugin to `pom.xml` (like suggested in this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-download-sources-javadoc); to download *sources* and *javadocs* of project dependencies):

```
<project>
  <!-- ... -->
  <build>
      <plugins>
          <!-- ... -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.2</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>sources</goal>
                <goal>resolve</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and running:

```
mvn clean install
```

the links are still missing in the generated HTML docs. However, Maven outputs these additional build log lines:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:sources (default) @ project ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    com.github.glusk:caesar:jar:javadoc:0.4.0 -- module caesar (auto)
[INFO]
[INFO] The following files have NOT been resolved:
[INFO]    com.github.glusk:caesar:jar:0.4.0:compile -- module com.github.glusk.caesar
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:resolve (default) @ project ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    com.github.glusk:caesar:jar:javadoc:0.4.0 -- module caesar (auto)
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have NOT been resolved:
[INFO]    com.github.glusk:caesar:jar:0.4.0:compile -- module com.github.glusk.caesar
[INFO]
[INFO]
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

Adding:

```xml
<links>
  <link>https://javadoc.io/doc/com.github.glusk/caesar/0.4.0</link>
</links>
```

to the `<configuration/>` tag of `maven-javadoc-plugin` adds class and package links but fails to include module links.

I'm expecting to see sections:

- **Packages** --> **Indirect Exports**
- **Modules** --> **Requires**

in `project/target/apidocs/foo.bar.project/module-summary.html`, much like [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.javadoc/module-summary.html#packages.summary), if I define my `module-info.java` as:

```
module foo.bar.project {
    requires transitive com.github.glusk.caesar;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #3**

The following Maven Javadoc Plugin `<configuration/>` block:

```
<configuration>
  <sourcepath>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourcepath>
  <links>
    <link>https://javadoc.io/doc/com.github.glusk/caesar/0.4.0</link>
  </links>
  <additionalOptions>
    <option>--show-module-contents all</option>
  </additionalOptions>
</configuration>
```

builds `project` docs with *links* to Caesar javadocs hosted at `https://javadoc.io`. Flag `--show-module-contents all` includes *all* module references, including `java.base`, which is not really what I want, because there are too many packages in that module and it clutters up the documentation.

On the other hand, the following configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <sourcepath>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourcepath>
  <additionalOptions>
    <option>--module foo.bar.project</option>
    <option>--expand-requires transitive</option>
  </additionalOptions>
</configuration>
```

*fetches* the dependency documentation from Maven Central and builds stand-alone docs. The only external links are those to the Java SE API. But it doesn't quite work: `mvn clean install` throws the following warnings:

```
[WARNING] Javadoc Warnings
[WARNING] javadoc: warning - module caesar not found.
[WARNING] javadoc: warning - module caesar not found.
```

and package documentation of module `com.github.glusk.caesar` is not included in the generated docs. However, `project/target/apidocs/foo.bar.project/module-summary.html` looks exactly like I want!

Comment: The Javadoc Plugin uses the Javadoc tool to generate javadocs for *your* project. Just download the javadoc of your dependencies: `mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc` Have look here: [baeldung maven-download-sources-javadoc](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-download-sources-javadoc)

Comment: @DirkDeyne I wonder if downloading *source* and *javadoc* files via `maven-dependency-plugin` has anything to do with `maven-javadoc-plugin`. It seems that `maven-dependency-plugin` merely pulls some files off of a remote repository. And those files can then be used by an IDE to show up pop-up docs or to let you view source files of your dependencies.

Comment: IIUC only transitive required modules end up as indirect export. Don't get confused by the word transitive: for Maven it means dependencies of direct dependencies, whereas for Java modules it means implied readability, so users of your module don't need to add a read on these in their descriptor

Comment: @RobertScholte It appears to be so, my mistake. But if I define my module dependency as `requires transitive com.github.glusk.caesar;`, it won't show up in my module doc under: "Modules" --> "Requires" and the packages it exports don't get listed under "Packages" --> "Indirect Exports".

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use a `@link` reference in your javadoc.

Something like:

```java
 /**
  * have a look here: {@link ImmutableMessageDigest}
  * @see <a href="https://github.com/Glusk/caesar">Glusk Caesar</a>
  */
 public void bar(){
   // your code
 }
```

In order to make *{@link ImmutableMessageDigest}* to be converted to an actual HTML link in your generated javadoc, you need to add a reference to the actual external javadoc.

This can be achieved by configuring a `link` in the `maven-javadoc-plugin`.

In your case, this would be `<link>https://javadoc.io/doc/com.github.glusk/caesar/0.4.0</link>`

To include `Indirect Exports` in the *module-summary.html* you need to add the (additional) option `--show-module-contents all`

resulting in:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.0</version>
       <configuration>
          <sourcepath>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourcepath>
          <!-- include this part -->
          <links>
             <link>https://javadoc.io/doc/com.github.glusk/caesar/0.4.0</link>
          </links>
          <additionalOptions>
             <option>--show-module-contents all</option>
          </additionalOptions>
       </configuration>
       <executions>
         <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
               <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
      </executions>
   </plugin>
```

Comment: What if you have maven modules and needs to reference a class from the other module?