# Maven JavaDoc plugin won't include the JavaDocs from an external local dependency on its final JavaDocs

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

I have a Maven project (let's call it A) that generates JavaDocs to itself through the JavaDoc plugin. I would like to also include the full JavaDocs of an external project (let's call it B), which I'm building on my local machine as well. Note that this external project is configured as a dependency on A, in other words, A has B configured as a dependency. My goal is to build A and instead of having JavaDocs just for A I would like to have a single JavaDocs for A and B generated.

I tried the  config, but no luck:

```
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
        <doclint>none</doclint>
                <links>
<link>jar:file:/Users/chris/workspace/MyDependency/target/apidocs/javadocs.jar!index.html</link>
                </links>

    </configuration> 
    <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

It does not fail, does not give me any warnings, but the external JavaDoc is not included in the final one for A.

Any help?

---

I'm not using modules. It is really an external maven project being built locally. It has its own JavaDocs inside its target/apidocs folder. I want to include (not reference) these JavaDocs on my top project generated JavaDocs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly link to a modularized dependency using the Maven Javadoc Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64843452/how-to-properly-link-to-a-modularized-dependency-using-the-maven-javadoc-plugin)

Comment: @Pino Thanks but unfortunately no. I'm not using modules. It is really an external maven project being built locally. It has its own JavaDocs inside its `target/apidocs` folder. I want to include (not reference) these JavaDocs on my top project.

Comment: Usually you link to other project and don't include them....